# Railroady how to include classes from all gems in application folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have problem with railroady gem (https://github.com/preston/railroady).

In my application root folder I have:

```
-app
-some_gem
-some_other_gem
-...<others standard folders>
```

I would like make diagrams using railroady, but it include only classes from app folder. I try to used all available options -m -a -p and so on but it didn't help. How to include classes from all gems in root folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Bundler to specify your gem dependencies, not store them in the root folder.

Comment: In gem file I had it in that form:
`gem "some_gem", :require => "some_gem", :path => "some_gem"`
`gem "some_other_gem", :require => "some_other_gem", :path => "some_other_gem"`

I thing its correct.